# is there a delay in setting session variables? failing on first attempt only

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a page, login.php, that processes a username and password and if successful it sets session variables and then redirects the user to home.php. The relevant part of login.php is here:

```
if ($pwdHash == $storedpass) {
            $success = true;
            $sessionStatus = session_status();
            if ($sessionStatus !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
                session_start();
            }
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            session_write_close();
            header('Location: http://www.examplesite.com/home.php');
            header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
            die("redirecting");
        }
```

Then home.php tries to collect the session variable

```
$sessionStatus = session_status();
if ($sessionStatus !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
$loggedIn = $_SESSION['logged_in'];
```

The problem is that on the **first** login attempt, $_SESSION['logged_in'] is undefined and generates an error, even though login.php was successful.

```
Notice: Undefined index: logged_in
```

A var_dump of $_SESSION returns an empty array, but sessionStatus reports that the session was already started, it did not have to execute session_start.

This forces the user to log in a second time, then everything is fine. So is the redirect just happening too fast for the session variable to get set? Should I put a delay in the redirect? (and how would I do that?) Or is this something else that I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I've checked with my host based on an answer to a similar question and confirmed that a session would never be served by more than one server and there is no need to enable sticky sessions or anything like that. I've also updated the code above based an answer offered below and some other research but the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

The session is probably automatically saved when the script ends. You redirect before the script ends.

How long your script takes to really end depends very much on what other code needs to wind down. It is better to explicitly save the session.

How to do this depends on what kind of sessions you use. One type can be closed like this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

If that's the one you're using do this:

```
if ($pwdHash == $storedpass) {
  $success = true;
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user;
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
  session_write_close();
  header('Location: http://www.examplesite.com/home.php');
  header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
  die("redirecting");
}
```

And the session should be available to the next page when you redirect.

If your sessions work differently, you have to adapt the code, of course. The point I'm trying to make is: Never put a delay in your code. It's unreliable, and pointless. Simply save the session before you redirect.

Comment: I wasn't aware there were different kinds of sessions, but this did not work. I still get the error "Notice: Undefined index: logged_in in..." The session calls you see in that code are the first I use, did I need to initialize the session somehow perhaps? Still odd that it works fine on the second login.

Comment: After some googling I added a session_start() before setting the variables but still get the same error.

Comment: still failing. I've updated the code and added some new information above.

Comment: Encountered the issue too but only occur upon uploading my website to an online server. Offline server works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This problem persists.  In my case, the user login goes without a problem to the protected homepage, but clicking on a menu link causes the user to be dumped back to the login page to login again. A check on certain Session values (required for both pages) shows these are not set on going to the specific menu link (while other menu links cause no problem).  The code requiring a session value is the same in all cases. Not all users experience the problem.  Seems that those with less robust connections to the internet always experience this problem. Others, never.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by noting that the one link that caused a user to have to log in twice, despite the fact session values were set correctly on the initial log in, was to eliminate GET parameters from the link.  These were intended to set defaults for a resulting table, but can be set in the php generating the table. Not having GET parameters in the link was the solution for eliminating the annoying requirement to  log back in shortly after a successful log in.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue while writing the session content to the database. 
To make it work I have added the sleep() function before setting the session variable, just like below.

```
sleep(2);
$_SESSION['GUID'] = uniqid(time().rand());
```

It resolves the issue for me.

We have observed this issue when the page hits are frequent but if one or two users are accessing the page it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this same issue with a login page but none of the suggestions work for me. The only thing I've found that does work is redirecting the page to itself after 1 second and then checking the session variables to see if the login was successful...

```
startSession(); // assigns all the login session variables, etc.
header('Refresh: 1; URL=/[THIS_PAGE].php'); // [THIS_PAGE] = the current login page
```

However, this is a very inelegant solution and I don't like using it. But it "works".